# Firebase robo test in Test lab runs for less than 2 mins everytime

Tags: android, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

Our team is exploring firebase robo test and the test only runs for less than 2 mins. We are using the script and script is only for a minute.

From the guide, I understand it uses the script as a guide and later on, explores the app as usual. But I just see it exploring for few secs after going through the script.

In the Test setting, I clearly mentioned it to run for 30 mins. Is this because my script is only for less than 2 mins ?

Comment: It's impossible to say, not knowing anything about your app.  If you want a discussion about Test Lab features, join the #test-lab channel on the Firebase Slack.  http://firebase.community/

Answer (score 0):

We recently a fixed a bug that could have caused this scenario. Have you encountered this problem after 12/21?

Thanks for the report!